# Android facebook login works on debug mode, never in release

Tags: android, facebook, key, release-management

I've developed an app for android and now its time to make a release version. But while I have no problems while debugging, I never could make work the releases. I've tried one hundred times by following this guidelines and they always led me to have keyhashes not working using facebook. Is there any kind of suggestion for cases like these? I've searched everywhere, but never found the key to get it working.

Comment: When you create a release, you're potentially using a different keystore with a different alias. Follow the same steps you used when creating the initial key hash for you debug keys, but with the new keystore/alias, and add that key hash to your dev settings as well.

Comment: I try often with the export signed android application tool of eclipse, i get the apk and the keytool. Then I calculate the SHA1 for the keystore, add the key hash on facebook app profile but nothing.

Comment: Please put in some debugging logs in appropriate areas of your code and paste the result here so we could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

i doubt it will aid u after 2 years, but someone else might need the an answer.

for debug i used the default debug keys this way (inside the java/bin lib):
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\myUserName\myFolder\viboKey.keystore" | "C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\openssl64\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\openssl64\bin\openssl" base64

It worked until i tried to create an APK with my own key from eclipse.
Then i had to change the path and the alias:

keytool -exportcert -alias v****key -keystore "C:\Users\myUserName\myFolder\v****Key.keystore" | "C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\openssl64\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\myUserName\Desktop\openssl64\bin\openssl" base64

note that when you enter the wrong pass, it gives you some default hash answer. verify you enter the right pass by entering two wrong ones and get the same wrong answer.

i hope it will help someone, gl :P